# Why do some nodes use "position" and others use "rect_position"?

Tags: godot, gdscript

What's the technical reason for this? It seems strange to me that they can't all just use position. Is it a legacy thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three relevant sets of nodes. Those that extend:

- `Control`, it is here where you find `rect_position`.
- `Node2D`, it is here where you find `position`.
- `Spatial`, and here you only find `transform`.

*These nodes are color coded. All `Control`s are green, all `Node2D` are blue, and all `Spatial`s are red. And yes, that is an accessibility concern regarding color vision deficiency. There is a call for an icon redesign here: [Tweak editor node icons to be distinguishable without relying on color (colorblind-friendly)](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/794).*

And yes, there is some naming mess. For starter 2D nodes say "2D" in the name, but 3D nodes don't (e.g. `Camera` vs `Camera2D`). That in particular has changed for Godot 4.0.

If you have ideas of how the naming can be better, you may open a proposal ([as an issue on github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/)).

Let us talk about how the positioning of these sets of nodes differ…

---

**On Transforms**

`Spatial` nodes use `Transform`. In fact, some people has proposed renaming the `transform` property to "position". Which, as you would know, is not the same thing, because a `Transform` not only has position but also rotation, scaling, and such.

I know you didn't ask about `transform`. However, you need to know that a `Node2D` also has a `transform` property, of type - you gusseted - `Transform2D`. And this is how a `Node2D` is actually positioned.  Meanwhile `position`, `rotation`, `rotation_degrees` and `scale` are for ease of use.

---

**Positioning Controls**

`Spatial` and `Node2D` have `transform`. Guess what? `Control` does not. Instead a `Control` is intended to be positioned in one of these ways:

- It is placed in a `Container` (Which are also `Control`s), and the `Container` decides how it is positioned, taking into account "Size Flags" (that is what they are for).
- By anchors (`anchor_*`) and margins (`margin_*`). The abstract is that the anchors are factors, and the margins are offset. For example, the leftmost part of the control will be positioned at `anchor_left * parent_width + margin_left`.
- By `rect_position` and `rect_size`. Where `rect_position` is position from the top left corner of parent.

One caveat: `rect_min_size` is uphold. *And yes, there is also `rect_rotation` and `rect_scale` which throw a wrench on the above explanation, but it works as one would imagine.*

And I say *intended* because you can mix these. For example, you can position a control by anchors and margins, or by placing it in a `Container`, but then animate the `rect_position` for effect.

---

As you can see, `position` and `rect_position` are two different things. *It is not the case that some nodes got stuck with one name or the other or something like that.*

I should also mention that there are "global" version of these properties, because they are positioned respect to their parent.

---

**On the prefix**

*Ok, they are different, but they do - to a first approximation - the same thing. Why can't they have the same name?*

Beyond it being a reminder that they aren't the same thing. There is a reason to prefix properties in Godot. And that is to ease grouping them in the inspector panel.

For example, the "Anchor" group will have all the properties which name begin with `anchor`, and that prefix is not shown on the name of the property.

Similarly, one of the groups you find is "Rect". And yes, `rect_position` is inside. Along side related properties. This also helps in discovering these properties from the code editors, since they would show up together in autocomplete.

*This all should make it easier for new user to figure out how `Control` positioning works. However, let us be honest, it is not working great. See also the proposal: [Redesign how user interface (Controls) scaling is presented to the user](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/2841).*

---

**Controls inside Node2D**

You can - and you may need to - place `Control`s inside of a `Node2D`. For example, if you want a `Label` or a `ProgressBar` (which are `Control`) following a `Node2D`.

Godot will handle the position. But you will find problems with scaling and centering, because `Node2D` don't have a size that the `Control`s can use (some - such as `Sprite` - have a visual size as virtue of their `Texture`, which is not exposed as a property, and `Control` does not use it).

*It is there where may want to hack it with some code that mixes `rect_position` and `position`.*

Centering a `Control` in a `Node2D` is not hard per se (there are `Containers`, anchors and margins, and good old hand positioning). The problem is keeping it centered when the it changes size. In particular when you add more text to a `Label`, which insist in growing to the right despite all odds. But do not fret, what you need is to handle the `resized` signal and there call `set_anchors_and_margins_preset`, which is what you do from the "Layout" option in the editor.

---

**Node2D inside Controls**

You may also place a `Node2D` inside a `Control`, and again Godot will handle the position. *You may want to set `rect_clip_content` on the `Control`.*

However, placing a `Node2D` inside a `Container` does not work properly. The `Container` cannot handle `Node2D` children.

If you are trying to do that, chances are that you need to do one of these:

- Change a `Sprite` (a `Node2D`) to a `TextureRect` (a `Control`).
- Change a `TouchScreenButton` (a `Node2D`) to a `Button` (a `Control`) and enable touch emulation in Project Settings -> Input Devices -> Pointing.
- Have a `Viewport` with a `Camera2D` along side whatever `Node2D` you want to display there. *Which I recommend to make as a separate scene for ease of design*. Don't forget to give size to the `Viewport`. And then, either:

  - Place that `Viewport` inside of a `ViewportContainer` (a `Control`). *You may want to set the `stretch` of the `ViewportContainer` to true*.
  - Or use a `TextureRect` with a `ViewportTexture`.

---

While I'm at it, I'll also suggest to make the root of your main scene a `Node` (not any derived type), and then use `CanvasLayer`s to separate the UI from the game world. That will prevent the `Camera2D` from affecting the UI.