# How to set and get position of an Object in Godot (3D)

Tags: position, godot, gdscript

I have a question - how do I get and set the position of object in Godot? I couldn't find any tutorials, so I need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So we have three kinds of `Node`s by their positioning rules: `Control`, `Node2D`, and `Spatial`. Since you mention 3D, I'll talk about `Spatial` on this answer.

*You can find the differences between `Node2D` and `Control` on [Why do some nodes use "position" and others use "rect_position"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68462253/402022). I also talk a little bit about `Spatial` there.*

---

**Spatial**

The way `Spatial` are placed is by their `Transform`. *This is similar to how `Node2D` are placed by their `Transform2D`.*

You might expect `Spatial` to have a "position" property, the way `Node2D` has one. However they don't. Instead they have a `translation` property. So you would get or set that instead, for example:

```
translation = Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

*However, there is no "global_translation". I'll get to how to workaround that.*

**Godot 4 Note**: In Godot 4 `Spatial` has been renamed to `Node3D`, and they do have `position` instead of `translation`. *Although no "global_position".*

---

I was saying that `Spatial` nodes are placed by their `Transform`. A `Transform` has two parts:

- A `Basis` called `basis`. Which you can conceptualize as a set of three `Vector3` that defines the axis of the coordinate system of the `Spatial`, or as a 3 by 3 matrix.
- A `Vector3` called `origin`. Which you can conceptualize as the origin position (aha!) of the coordinate system of the `Spatial`, or as vector that augments the 3 by 3 matrix to add a translation to the transformation.

Thus, you can place `Spatial` nodes by setting the `origin` of their `Transform` (which is equivalent to setting `translation`). For example:

```
transform.orign = Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

---

It is worth noting that a `Spatial` has a `transform` property which is relative to their parent, and a `global_transform` which we will say it is relative to the world. *If you compose (multiply, as in "matrix multiplication") all the `transform` from the root of the scene tree to your `Spatial`, you would have computed its `global_transform`.*

You can directly get or set the `origin` of the `global_transform`. For example:

```
global_transform.orign = Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

And this would be the equivalent to the missing "global_translation"/"global_position".

---

**RigidBody**

I also want to point out that directly modifying the transform of a `RigidBody` might be undesirable. To be more precise, the physics engine that Godot is using might want to move the `RigidBody`, and then you end up fighting the physics engine.

With that said. If you need to teleport a `RigidBody`, you can request it to the physics engine, like this:

```
PhysicsServer.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    PhysicsServer.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform.IDENTITY.translated(Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
)
```

*Yes, this works regardless of its `mode`. In fact, in my experience, this approach is better than switching modes.*