# Set a Rigid body position in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am following a course for Godot 3 but I am using Godot 4. In the course a 2D object is instantiated and placed at a random point in the scene using

```
Object.transform = Transform2D(Vector2(X,Y)
```

So it returns "parser error: no constructor of "Transform2D" matches the signature "Transform2D(Vector2D)"
How can I fix it?

I already tried with position and global_position but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you only want to change the position of a transform, you can set its `origin`.

And yes, you could write to `position` or `global_position`.

However, none of that would work with a rigid body.

The reason why is because the physics server is in charge of moving the rigid body, so when you set its position you are fighting it (you move it, and the physics server moves it back).

*You could take charge of the motion of the rigid body by "freezing" to kinematic mode, but there is an easier and better solution if you only want to set the position...*

---

I have answered variations of this question before.

- 2D, Godot 3 (and updated to cover Godot 4): [(GDScript) Trying to either teleport the ball back into the middle of the screen or queue_free() the current ball and create a new instance of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902594/402022).
- 3D, Godot 3: [How to set and get position of an Object in Godot (3D)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72459978/402022).

I could vote to close this as a duplicate, but instead I'll take the opportunity to consolidate the answers here.

---

The following code tells the physics server to move the rigid body where you want it.

Godot 3, `RigidBody2D`:

```
Physics2DServer.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    Physics2DServer.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(Vector2(1.0, 2.0))
)
```

Godot 3, `RigidBody`:

```
PhysicsServer.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    PhysicsServer.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform.IDENTITY.translated(Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
)
```

Godot 4, `RigidBody2D`:

```
PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(Vector2(1.0, 2.0))
)
```

And the elusive correct way to teleport a `RigidBody3D` in Godot 4:

```
PhysicsServer3D.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    PhysicsServer3D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform3D.IDENTITY.translated(Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
)
```

*Of course, you would pass the vector with the position you want.*

---

These codes are meant to run on an script attached to the rigid body. If you need to run them somewhere else, you need to get the result of `get_rid()` from a reference to the rigid body you want. And, of course, you can change the vector to the position want.

They also serves as an example of creating a translation transform (although it is not the only way to do it).

A transform, as you would know, can represent more than just a translation (they can represent rotation, scaling, skewing and mirroring too) so the transform does not have a constructor that simply takes a vector. *Hence the error in question.*

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't find the other threads you mention so I'm sorry you had to respond to the same type of question again.
In another notes, when I introduce the proposed code it returns the error: function "get_rid()" not found inbase self.
Anyway, again, thank you for your replay

Comment: @anonymus As I mention in the answer, the code is intended for a script attached on the rigid body. If you need this code somewhere else, you need a reference to the rigid body to can `get_rid` on it, e.g: `my_rigid_body.get_rid()`.

Comment: I have the following code: extends Node2D

func  crearfruta():
 var platano = load("res://pool/recolectable.tscn")
 print("antes de instance")
 var mi_platano = platano.instantiate()
 
 var mi_platano_localización = get_node("res://pool/recolectable.tscn")
 PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(mi_platano.get_rid(),PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(Vector2(randf_range(0,50), randf_range(0,20))))
 add_child(mi_platano)

func _on_timer_timeout():
 crearfruta()
And it returns: Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_rid' in base 'Node(recolectable_main.gd

Comment: @anonymus Apparently `mi_platano` is not a rigid body, and you are trying to set its position before adding it to the scene tree. See [Why isnt my spike shooters child showing up in the scene in godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77277265/402022).